# UIPageControl + UIScrollView not counting pages properly

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I am having an issue with a UIPageControl incrementing the `currentPage` past an arrays count - 1.  For example; if there are 5 items in the array, it will actually draw 5 dots, but it will only go to number 4.  The control is incremented or decreased based on the paging of the `UIScrollView` up to (what I thought would be) the maximum number of items in the given array.    Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code for the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
CGFloat pageWidth = _meatSelectionCollection.frame.size.width;
self.pageControl.currentPage = _meatSelectionCollection.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;
NSLog(@"Current Page Test: %ld", (long)self.pageControl.currentPage);
}
```

I'm detecting the page width in the UIScrollView that determines the current page, and paging in the scroll view is enabled.  However, the `NSLog` for the current page reads the following output as the page changes:

```
2014-09-02 21:41:28.359 Burger Grinder[73531:60b] Current Page Test: 0
2014-09-02 21:41:29.420 Burger Grinder[73531:60b] Current Page Test: 1
2014-09-02 21:41:30.120 Burger Grinder[73531:60b] Current Page Test: 2
2014-09-02 21:41:30.870 Burger Grinder[73531:60b] Current Page Test: 3
2014-09-02 21:41:31.708 Burger Grinder[73531:60b] Current Page Test: 4
2014-09-02 21:41:32.476 Burger Grinder[73531:60b] Current Page Test: 4
```

It's not incrementing past 4.  The array count that is determining it is returning as 6.  I understand that `self.page.currentPage` showing `4` is the result of counting `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` (i.e. 5 elements), but the count is 6.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?  Thanks in advance.

EDIT:  Showing Content Offset and PageWidth Logs after increment:

```
2014-09-02 22:03:52.472 Burger Grinder[73813:60b] Current Page Test: 1
2014-09-02 22:03:52.472 Burger Grinder[73813:60b] Content Offset.x Value: 244.000000
2014-09-02 22:03:52.473 Burger Grinder[73813:60b] PageWidth: 244.000000
2014-09-02 22:03:55.811 Burger Grinder[73813:60b] Current Page Test: 2
2014-09-02 22:03:55.811 Burger Grinder[73813:60b] Content Offset.x Value: 488.000000
2014-09-02 22:03:55.812 Burger Grinder[73813:60b] PageWidth: 244.000000
```

In fact, `Content Offset.x Value` increments even if the count doesn't increase past 4.  It correctly logs the value as `1213` at the highest level page, but the counter doesn't increase.

Comment: What about the log of `contentOffset.x` and `pageWidth`?

Comment: @trick14 edited to add values.

Comment: Are you sure that your scrollView has six pages? What's the value of `scorollView.contentSize.width`?

Comment: The `content.offset.x` maxes out at `1213`, but the `scrollView.width` is logging as `1457`.  With a default width of `244`, `1457 / 244 = 6`

Comment: The content offset x of 1st page must be 0, `page2-offset 244`, `page3-732`, `page4-976`, `page5-1220`. Where's the `1213` from? If the content offset was 1213 and width 244, `1213 / 244 = 4.xxxx` It means the count of page will be 4.

Comment: It's logging as `0` on `viewDidLoad` and correctly logs `0` when the user scrolls back to the first page.  I'm stumped

Comment: Track why the content offset is not as expected. Try log the 3rd and 4th page. It must not be a hard problem to track.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue with the calculation of `currentPage`.  Re-tooled below:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
CGFloat pageWidth = _meatSelectionCollection.frame.size.width;
//    self.pageControl.currentPage = _meatSelectionCollection.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;

// This is where it needed to be calculated correctly rather then the line above it.

int page = floor((_meatSelectionCollection.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1; 

self.pageControl.currentPage = page;


NSLog(@"Current Page Test: %ld", (long)self.pageControl.currentPage);
NSLog(@"Content Offset.x Value: %f", _meatSelectionCollection.contentOffset.x);
NSLog(@"PageWidth: %f", pageWidth);
NSLog(@"Scroll View: %f", scrollView.contentSize.width);
}
```